# Select a html element that will be created after ajax job

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm tying to add custom right click context menu with **jQuery**
on (.message) element what will be available after `foreach` loop.

In my index html file i have div by id (show_case)
**chat.php**

```
 foreach ($messages as $key => $value) { ?>
            <div class="message">
                <p class="username"><?php echo $value['username']; ?></p> <span>say:</span>
                <p class="text"> <?php echo $value['message']; ?></p>
            </div> <?php }
    }
```

chat.js used jQuery/ajax

```
chat.fetchMessages = function () {

    var data = {method: "fetch"}
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/chat.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#show_case').html(data);
        }

    });
}
```

Now I want to select div with class message in `foreach` loop to handle my context menu options
**menu.js**

```
$('document').ready(function()
{
    $(".message").on("contextmenu", function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var menu = $(".menu");
        menu.hide();
        //let get xposiion;
        var xpos = e.pageX;
        var ypos = e.pageY;

        menu.css({
            top: ypos,
            left: xpos
        });
                menu.show(200);
```

I can't select it but it doesn't work. What should I do?

Comment: Read up on ***[Event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)***

Comment: where is element of `.menu`

Comment: .menu is in index html file it is a list menu that is fine

Comment: charlietfl i think my problem is little diffrent in comparison this article